# How to run shell script after MacOS reboot

Tags: macos, shell, cron, plist

I have written a shell script in macOS to run a program. through the command line, I'm able to run the script from anywhere.

I have written .plist service and stored it into /Library/LaunchAgents/. I perform load and start functionality. After that when I rebooted the system but script not executed.

In the sh file I'm opening .app file using open filename.app.

Also, I tried another way like running with Automator when I'm trying to run .app file in Automator it's giving me lsopenurlswithrole() failed 10810 error.

I store .plist file in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ and /Library/LaunchDaemons/ but still got no result.

I also put .plist file in system preference -> User & group -> Login Items. But after reboot, it opens the shell script not execute it not run the command in that.

Below is my .plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN” “https://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-l.0.dtd“>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.start.activity</strings>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</strings
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/rwm.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Anyone, Please help me out from this.

Comment: In .sh file I'm opening .app file using open filename.app

Comment: Also, I tried another way like running with Automator 

when I'm trying to run .app file in Automator it's giving me lsopenurlswithrole() failed 10810 error

Comment: Try setting the standard error path to a file in `/tmp` to see error messages. Try using full paths, e.g. `/bin/sh` and `/usr/bin/open` Check here... https://www.launchd.info/

Comment: Oh, you are still there. Was there any output in the file you redirected `StandardError` to?

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing these in the plist file:

```
<key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
<true/>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<false/>
```

I have a similar script and needed those to have it run properly. Note, if you need this program to open a pty/tty and some other things, they will be blocked by newer macOS security features.

If you see an error `lsopenurlswithrole() failed 10810`, Launch Services is having trouble launching the application.